# How to order by twice with MongoDB, Mongoose, and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of `Product` documents and each one of these documents has a `createdAt` field. I want to do a `Product.find({}).sort('createdAt')` and then randomize the order of all `Product` documents created on the same day. So for example, let's say I have 6 `Product`s:

```
{_id: 1, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 2, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 3, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 4, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}, 
{_id: 5, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}, 
{_id: 6, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}
```

A potential resulting query could be:

```
{_id: 3, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 1, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 2, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 6, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}, 
{_id: 4, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}, 
{_id: 5, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}
```

or it could be:

```
{_id: 1, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 2, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 3, createdAt: '2019-01-01'}, 
{_id: 4, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}, 
{_id: 5, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}, 
{_id: 6, createdAt: '2019-01-02'}
```

I literally have no idea how to start going about this, so I can't post code about what I've tried. I know that the first thing to do would probably be to do:

`db.Product.find({}).sort('createdAt')` and then I feel like there would need to be some sort of aggregation query afterward. Any documentation that might point me in the right direction would be great as well! Thanks!

Comment: I think you should first randomise the data set and then perform a sort, since there is no order by clause for id, the id's should in theory show up in random order. You could try the sample operator but there are performance considerations to be made. https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample

Comment: Why don't you generate new array by choosing an arbitrary document sequentially, let's say with Math.random()